# customize user to user request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request, facebook-rest-api, facebook-requests

Is there a way to customize the user to user request link in the notification the recepient receives in his/her notifications jewel?  I'm trying to direct the receipient of the request to a specific competition room upon clicking on the notification.

Example - A request is sent to the user to be a pitcher in a particular baseball game (Yankees vs. cubs), can the user request notification take him to the particular baseball game and not just the home page or game directory?  Otherwise how will the player know what the request is for or where to go upon ariving on the home canvas page?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know I am very late answering this question. But I too faced a lot of difficulty figuring this out at the beginning. I hope my answer would help others facing the same difficulty too.

There is a **data** parameter for each request object. You can [find out about the parameters here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). This can be used to track which object is being sent/received. For example, you can use an integer or a string on your client side to tell you which kind of object the particular request is. The sample FB.ui call may look like this:

```
var obj = {
    method: 'apprequests',
    title: 'Here\'s something to help you out.',
    message: s_message,
    data: i_giftIndex
};

FB.ui(obj, GiftCallback);
```